# JRuby keeps JAR file locked after application is shut down

Tags: java, jar, websphere, jruby

I did some research about this issue and unable to find solution.
I have a web application and one jar file uses JRuby ScriptingContainer class to call ruby script compile.rb. The compile.rb is packaged in the jar file. The application works well. The only problem is that the jar file has been locked by Websphere application server java process and the jar file cannot be deleted after the web application is uninstalled.

I also confirmed that the reason why the jar cannot be uninstalled is because the program has executed the ruby script using ScriptingContainer class.

The terminate() method was also called in the code successfully. I cannot find any solution to this problem and it seems to me that JRuby class has caused the jar file locked for whatever reason I don't know.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: So don't use Windows?

Comment: It seems that the problem is solved by moving Ruby script and Gems libraries out of the jar.